# Remove Openjdk 7, install Openjdk 6?

Tags: java, android, openjdk

I need to be using Openjdk 6 but cannot figure out how remove Openjdk 7. I used the apt-get purge command and it seems to be successful but even after installing Openjdk 6,

```
java -version
```

always returns

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.13.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install OpenJDK 6 using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre` and set it as default using `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and then selecting the OpenJDK 6 one.